# Hard drive Incorrect Serial Number

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I am trying to get serial number of hard drives in Centos, but for some hard drives I am getting incorrect serial numbers when compared the serial number printed on drive label.

I am using `lsblk` command... I have also tried `smartctl`, `sginfo` and `hdparm` with same result.

example, on drive label, serial number printed is `PBV69P2E` while `lsblk` and `smartctl` are returning `PBV69P2ECCXSA610`

so I would like to know, how can I get the actual serial number?

additionally, does linux store a drive's serial number in a file just like vendor `/sys/block/sdX/device/vendor`

Thanks

Comment: Strangely the SN is wrote in the output, the question could be what is the added string, model?

Comment: @yagmoth555 yes, actual serial number is part of returned serial number, couldn't figure out what additional letters are, they are certainly not the model number ... could be drive's firmware have different serial number than what's printed on label?

Comment: I wonder if the printel label has a mistake, based on the fact that today im looking for a WWN that ended as `500AECCD07B` based on ZFS output that kept the drive stats, when i finally had the drive in hand, the label actuall says `500AECCD078`  Ive checked and rechecked with zoom glasses, the `8` on the label is a mismatch for the `B` that the system sees.  Im thinking it was the Label Printers(data entry person?) Eyes that were bad that day!!  In your case, maybe a tad of lameness from the data entry person??

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for myself for RHEL7 and other distros.    There is a bug in linux-utils that causes WWN to be reported in place of the serial.  Using udevadm resolves this.

Ive used the following

`udevadm info -q property --path=/sys/block/sdX | grep ID_SCSI_SERIAL`

`udevadm info --path=/sys/block/sdX`

e.g. Unexpected results

```
$ lsblk -d -o name,serial /dev/sdh
NAME SERIAL
sdh  50000c0f01e63ff0
```

Expected results

```
$ udevadm info -q property --path=/sys/block/sdh | grep ID_SCSI_SERIAL
ID_SCSI_SERIAL=WMC1F1896569
```

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1328771

https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/1143